# Laser scan topic returns many messages

Tags: laser, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using a very simple subscription to a /scan topic to get the laser distances that my hokuyo laser scanner has grabbed, using:

```
scan_msg = rospy.Subscriber("/scan", LaserScan, scan_message, queue_size=1)
```

but when I print out the returning message I get 3 message packets, not 1 as expected. Why?

Code:

```
rospy.init_node("node1")
def scan_message(msg):
        laser_range = msg.ranges
        print "Range: ",laser_range
    
    
 scan_msg = rospy.Subscriber("/scan", LaserScan, scan_message, queue_size=1)
```

Result:

Range: (inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, 2.886342763900757, 2.874502420425415, 2.8628132343292236, 2.8512728214263916, 2.839879274368286, 2.828630208969116, 2.817523241043091, 2.8065567016601562, 2.7957284450531006, 2.785036087036133, 2.7744781970977783, 2.764052629470825, 2.7537574768066406, 2.743590831756592, 2.733551025390625, 2.7236363887786865, 2.7138447761535645, 2.7041749954223633, 2.694624900817871, 2.6851933002471924, 2.6758782863616943, 2.6666784286499023, 2.657592296600342, 2.648618221282959, 2.6397545337677, 2.631000280380249, 2.6223537921905518, 2.613813638687134, 2.6053783893585205, 2.5970470905303955, 2.588818073272705, 2.5806901454925537, 2.572661876678467, 2.564732313156128, 2.5569002628326416, 2.549164295196533, 2.5415234565734863, 2.5339765548706055, 2.526522397994995, 2.5191597938537598, 2.511888027191162, 2.5047056674957275, 2.4976117610931396, 2.490605354309082, 2.4836854934692383, 2.476851224899292, 2.4701013565063477, 2.463434934616089, 2.4568514823913574, 2.4503495693206787, 2.4439284801483154, 2.4375874996185303, 2.431325674057007, 2.4251420497894287, 2.4190359115600586, 2.41300630569458, 2.407052516937256, 2.4011738300323486, 2.395369529724121, 2.389638662338257, 2.3839805126190186, 2.378394365310669, 2.3728795051574707, 2.3674352169036865, 2.362061023712158, 2.3567559719085693, 2.3515193462371826, 2.346350908279419, 2.341249465942383, 2.336214780807495, 2.3312461376190186, 2.326343059539795, 2.3289997577667236, 2.3506991863250732, 2.3728525638580322, 2.3954737186431885, 2.418576717376709, 2.4421770572662354, 2.466289758682251, 2.490931749343872, 2.5161192417144775, 2.541870594024658, 2.568204164505005, 2.5951387882232666, 2.622695207595825, 2.6508941650390625, 2.679757833480835, 2.7093093395233154, 2.739572763442993, 2.770573377609253, 2.802337646484375, 2.8348937034606934, 2.8682701587677, 2.902498245239258, 2.9376096725463867, 2.9736385345458984, 3.010620355606079, 3.0485925674438477, 3.087594509124756, 3.1276679039001465, 3.168856382369995, 3.2112061977386475, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, 3.260653495788574, 3.2153172492980957, 3.1712844371795654, 3.128499984741211, 3.0869128704071045, 3.0464742183685303, 3.007138252258301, 2.9688608646392822, 2.931601047515869, 2.8953194618225098, 2.859978675842285, 2.8255438804626465, 2.791980743408203, 2.7592580318450928, 2.7273447513580322, 2.69621205329895, 2.66583251953125, 2.6361796855926514, 2.6072285175323486, 2.5789549350738525, 2.5513362884521484, 2.524350643157959, 2.4979770183563232, 2.4721953868865967, 2.4469869136810303, 2.422333002090454, 2.3982162475585938, 2.374619960784912, 2.3515279293060303, 2.3339428901672363, 2.3386147022247314, 2.3433501720428467, 2.3481497764587402, 2.3530139923095703, 2.357943534851074, 2.36293888092041, 2.3680007457733154, 2.3731298446655273, 2.378326892852783, 2.383592128753662, 2.3889265060424805, 2.3943305015563965, 2.3998050689697266, 2.405350685119629, 2.410968065261841, 2.4166581630706787, 2.422421455383301, 2.4282588958740234, 2.434170961380005, 2.4401586055755615, 2.4462225437164307, 2.4523637294769287, 2.458582878112793, 2.4648807048797607, 2.4712584018707275, 2.4777164459228516, 2.484255790710449, 2.490877628326416, 2.4975826740264893, 2.5043716430664062, 2.5112459659576416, 2.5182061195373535, 2.5252535343170166, 2.532388687133789, 2.5396132469177246, 2.5469276905059814, 2.554333209991455, 2.56183123588562, 2.569422483444214, 2.577108144760132, 2.5848894119262695, 2.5927674770355225, 2.600743532180786, 2.608818769454956, 2.6169943809509277, 2.625271797180176, 2.6336522102355957, 2.642136812210083, 2.6507270336151123, 2.659424066543579, 2.668229818344116, 2.677145004272461, 2.686171531677246, 2.6953108310699463, 2.704564332962036, 2.7139337062835693, 2.7234201431274414, 2.733025550842285, 2.7427515983581543, 2.7525999546051025, 2.7625720500946045, 2.772669792175293, 2.782895088195801, 2.7932493686676025, 2.8037350177764893, 2.8143532276153564, 2.825106620788574, 2.8359968662261963, 2.8470258712768555, 2.8581957817077637, 2.8695085048675537, 2.8809666633605957, 2.8925719261169434, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf)
Range: (inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, 2.8862366676330566, 2.8743977546691895, 2.8627097606658936, 2.851170539855957, 2.839778184890747, 2.8285303115844727, 2.8174245357513428, 2.8064591884613037, 2.7956318855285645, 2.7849409580230713, 2.774384021759033, 2.7639596462249756, 2.7536654472351074, 2.743499994277954, 2.7334611415863037, 2.7235474586486816, 2.713757038116455, 2.7040882110595703, 2.6945393085479736, 2.6851084232330322, 2.6757946014404297, 2.666595697402954, 2.657510280609131, 2.6485371589660645, 2.639674663543701, 2.6309211254119873, 2.6222755908966064, 2.613736391067505, 2.605302095413208, 2.5969715118408203, 2.588743209838867, 2.5806162357330322, 2.5725889205932617, 2.5646603107452393, 2.5568289756774902, 2.549093723297119, 2.5414538383483887, 2.533907651901245, 2.526454210281372, 2.519092321395874, 2.5118212699890137, 2.5046396255493164, 2.497546434402466, 2.4905409812927246, 2.483621835708618, 2.47678804397583, 2.470038890838623, 2.4633734226226807, 2.4567904472351074, 2.450289249420166, 2.443869113922119, 2.437528610229492, 2.431267499923706, 2.425084352493286, 2.4189789295196533, 2.412950038909912, 2.406996965408325, 2.401118755340576, 2.395314931869507, 2.38958477973938, 2.3839271068573, 2.3783416748046875, 2.3728275299072266, 2.3673837184906006, 2.3620100021362305, 2.356705665588379, 2.3514697551727295, 2.346301794052124, 2.341200828552246, 2.3361668586730957, 2.3311986923217773, 2.326296091079712, 2.3291618824005127, 2.350864887237549, 2.3730218410491943, 2.395646572113037, 2.4187536239624023, 2.4423577785491943, 2.466474771499634, 2.4911208152770996, 2.516312837600708, 2.5420687198638916, 2.568406820297241, 2.595346450805664, 2.622907876968384, 2.6511120796203613, 2.679980993270874, 2.709537982940674, 2.73980712890625, 2.7708137035369873, 2.802584171295166, 2.83514666557312, 2.868529796600342, 2.9027647972106934, 2.9378833770751953, 2.973919630050659, 3.010909080505371, 3.048889398574829, 3.087899684906006, 3.127981662750244, 3.1691792011260986, 3.211538553237915, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, 3.2602972984313965, 3.2149717807769775, 3.1709487438201904, 3.128174304962158, 3.0865964889526367, 3.0461668968200684, 3.0068392753601074, 2.9685702323913574, 2.9313182830810547, 2.8950443267822266, 2.859710931777954, 2.8252830505371094, 2.79172682762146, 2.7590105533599854, 2.7271034717559814, 2.695976972579956, 2.6656031608581543, 2.635956048965454, 2.6070103645324707, 2.578742027282715, 2.551128387451172, 2.5241477489471436, 2.49777889251709, 2.472001791000366, 2.4467978477478027, 2.4221482276916504, 2.398035764694214, 2.374443292617798, 2.3513553142547607, 2.3339736461639404, 2.3386459350585938, 2.343381881713867, 2.348181962966919, 2.3530466556549072, 2.3579766750335693, 2.3629724979400635, 2.368035078048706, 2.373164653778076, 2.3783621788024902, 2.3836278915405273, 2.388962745666504, 2.3943674564361572, 2.3998425006866455, 2.405388832092285, 2.4110069274902344, 2.4166975021362305, 2.4224612712860107, 2.4282991886138916, 2.4342119693756104, 2.440200090408325, 2.4462647438049316, 2.452406644821167, 2.4586262702941895, 2.4649248123168945, 2.4713029861450195, 2.477761745452881, 2.484301805496216, 2.49092435836792, 2.4976298809051514, 2.5044198036193848, 2.5112946033477783, 2.5182554721832275, 2.525303602218628, 2.5324394702911377, 2.5396647453308105, 2.5469799041748047, 2.5543861389160156, 2.561884880065918, 2.569476842880249, 2.5771632194519043, 2.5849452018737793, 2.5928242206573486, 2.6008009910583496, 2.608876943588257, 2.617053508758545, 2.6253316402435303, 2.6337127685546875, 2.642198324203491, 2.650789260864258, 2.659487247467041, 2.6682937145233154, 2.6772098541259766, 2.686237335205078, 2.6953775882720947, 2.704632043838501, 2.7140021324157715, 2.723489761352539, 2.733096122741699, 2.7428231239318848, 2.7526721954345703, 2.7626454830169678, 2.7727441787719727, 2.782970428466797, 2.793325901031494, 2.803812265396118, 2.81443190574646, 2.825186252593994, 2.8360774517059326, 2.847107410430908, 2.858278512954712, 2.8695926666259766, 2.881051778793335, 2.892658233642578, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf)
Range:  (inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, 2.8862721920013428, 2.8744325637817383, 2.8627443313598633, 2.8512046337127686, 2.8398118019104004, 2.8285634517669678, 2.817457437515259, 2.8064916133880615, 2.795663833618164, 2.7849724292755127, 2.7744152545928955, 2.7639904022216797, 2.7536959648132324, 2.743530035018921, 2.7334909439086914, 2.723576784133911, 2.7137858867645264, 2.7041168212890625, 2.6945674419403076, 2.685136318206787, 2.6758220195770264, 2.6666228771209717, 2.6575372219085693, 2.6485636234283447, 2.6397006511688232, 2.6309471130371094, 2.6223011016845703, 2.6137614250183105, 2.6053268909454346, 2.5969960689544678, 2.5887675285339355, 2.5806400775909424, 2.5726125240325928, 2.564683675765991, 2.556852102279663, 2.549116611480713, 2.541476249694824, 2.5339298248291016, 2.5264761447906494, 2.5191140174865723, 2.511842727661133, 2.5046608448028564, 2.4975674152374268, 2.4905614852905273, 2.483642101287842, 2.4768083095550537, 2.4700589179992676, 2.463392972946167, 2.4568097591400146, 2.4503085613250732, 2.443887948989868, 2.437547206878662, 2.431285858154297, 2.425102710723877, 2.418996810913086, 2.4129676818847656, 2.4070143699645996, 2.4011361598968506, 2.395332098007202, 2.389601469039917, 2.383943796157837, 2.3783581256866455, 2.3728437423706055, 2.3673996925354004, 2.3620259761810303, 2.3567211627960205, 2.351485013961792, 2.3463168144226074, 2.3412158489227295, 2.336181640625, 2.3312132358551025, 2.326310396194458, 2.329101324081421, 2.3508028984069824, 2.3729586601257324, 2.3955819606781006, 2.418687582015991, 2.4422903060913086, 2.4664058685302734, 2.4910502433776855, 2.5162405967712402, 2.54199481010437, 2.568331241607666, 2.595268964767456, 2.622828483581543, 2.6510307788848877, 2.6798980236053467, 2.7094528675079346, 2.739719867706299, 2.770724296569824, 2.802492380142212, 2.835052490234375, 2.8684332370758057, 2.902665615081787, 2.937781572341919, 2.9738152027130127, 3.0108017921447754, 3.048779010772705, 3.0877861976623535, 3.1278650760650635, 3.1690592765808105, 3.2114150524139404, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, 3.260429620742798, 3.215100049972534, 3.1710734367370605, 3.128295421600342, 3.086714029312134, 3.046281099319458, 3.0069503784179688, 2.9686782360076904, 2.9314234256744385, 2.895146608352661, 2.8598105907440186, 2.8253800868988037, 2.7918214797973633, 2.7591025829315186, 2.7271933555603027, 2.6960644721984863, 2.6656887531280518, 2.6360392570495605, 2.6070916652679443, 2.5788214206695557, 2.551206111907959, 2.5242233276367188, 2.4978528022766113, 2.472074031829834, 2.446868419647217, 2.4222171306610107, 2.3981032371520996, 2.374509334564209, 2.351419687271118, 2.3339595794677734, 2.3386316299438477, 2.343367338180542, 2.3481671810150146, 2.353031873703003, 2.357961654663086, 2.36295747756958, 2.3680195808410645, 2.3731491565704346, 2.3783462047576904, 2.3836119174957275, 2.388946533203125, 2.394351005554199, 2.3998260498046875, 2.405371904373169, 2.410989761352539, 2.416680097579956, 2.4224438667297363, 2.428281545639038, 2.4341938495635986, 2.4401819705963135, 2.446246385574341, 2.452387809753418, 2.4586074352264404, 2.4649057388305664, 2.4712836742401123, 2.4777421951293945, 2.4842820167541504, 2.4909043312072754, 2.4976096153259277, 2.504399061203003, 2.5112738609313965, 2.5182344913482666, 2.525282144546509, 2.5324177742004395, 2.539642810821533, 2.5469577312469482, 2.55436372756958, 2.561861991882324, 2.569453716278076, 2.5771398544311523, 2.5849215984344482, 2.5928003787994385, 2.6007769107818604, 2.6088526248931885, 2.6170287132263184, 2.6253066062927246, 2.6336874961853027, 2.6421725749969482, 2.6507632732391357, 2.65946102142334, 2.668267011642456, 2.677182912826538, 2.6862101554870605, 2.695349931716919, 2.704603910446167, 2.7139737606048584, 2.7234609127044678, 2.733067035675049, 2.742793560028076, 2.7526423931121826, 2.762615203857422, 2.7727136611938477, 2.7829394340515137, 2.7932944297790527, 2.8037805557250977, 2.8143997192382812, 2.8251535892486572, 2.8360445499420166, 2.847074031829834, 2.8582446575164795, 2.869558334350586, 2.881016969680786, 2.89262318611145, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/346780/laser-scan-topic-returns-many-messages/) by [John999991](https://answers.ros.org/users/39040/john999991/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2020-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please look over ROS tutorials (http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers).

A subscriber object is not a message, its declaring a subscription to a topic with some parameters. The callback is what will process incoming messages. So in your example the `scan_msg` is actually a subscriber object and the `scan_message` is a callback function signature.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [John999991](https://answers.ros.org/users/39040/john999991/) on 2020-03-16**:
I have implemented the callback function from where I print out the message I receive. The problem is that I get 3 messages instead of 1.

**Comment by [pcoenen](https://answers.ros.org/users/30604/pcoenen/) on 2020-03-16**:
Please show that code and the output as well.

**Comment by [John999991](https://answers.ros.org/users/39040/john999991/) on 2020-03-16**:
I have added the important portion of my code on the original question.
Thank you.

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2020-03-16**:
Not sure what you mean by three message packets - what is leading you to say that is what is happening.

**Comment by [pcoenen](https://answers.ros.org/users/30604/pcoenen/) on 2020-03-16**:
Is any code missing? I don't understand where the `I heard` is coming from.

**Comment by [John999991](https://answers.ros.org/users/39040/john999991/) on 2020-03-16**:
Sorry, I fixed it.

**Comment by [John999991](https://answers.ros.org/users/39040/john999991/) on 2020-03-16**:
I get 3 times the Range: {values},  so I suppose I get the Sub to run 3 times...No?

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2020-03-16**:
I am assuming the laser scanner sends messages one after the other - is this just displaying multiple messages that have arrived, each one a separate call when a message is received. In the absence of other code it is impossible to say ?

The values are slightly different, so it is not the same thing that is being printed 3 times

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-16**:\

> so it is not the same thing that is being printed 3 times

exactly.

@John999991: your callback gets invoked 3 times, with 3 different messages.

"Subs" don't "run", only callbacks get invoked.

But perhaps it would be good to take a step back: what is it that you actually want to do? Why do you feel you  need to sample a single message from a topic to which messages are continuously being published?

**Comment by [John999991](https://answers.ros.org/users/39040/john999991/) on 2020-03-16**:
The idea is to take the incoming message, break down the values into chunks, estimate some distances and take a decision on where the robot should move next.
I guess I can live with that since It would make no difference in my come.
I was curious on why the callback got invoked 3 times, that's all...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A ROS subscriber runs continuously and gets all messages that are published on a topic until it is shut down. The callback is called once for each message.

In your case it looks like your program runs long enough to receive three messages before it stops, but I suspect that sometimes you will get 1, 2 or maybe 4 messages depending on timing and other CPU usage.

If you want to receive a single message on a topic, you need to create subscriber, wait for callback to be called once, and then unsubscribe; rospy has a function that does this for you: [`rospy.wait_for_message`](https://docs.ros.org/api/rospy/html/rospy.client-module.html#wait_for_message)

I haven't tested it, but this should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import LaserScan

rospy.init_node("subscribe_once")
message = rospy.wait_for_message("/scan", LaserScan)
print(message)
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2020-03-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-17**:
This is the answer.